# Firebase GetToken Returns at JWT - How do I get a device token?

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am attempting to store user Firebase device tokens on Firebase database in order to facilitate messages between users, however the token I get from this code:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken().then(function(token) {

   firebase.database().ref('notificationTokens/' + user.uid + '/' + token).set(true)    
   .then(function(result) {
     console.log(result);    
   })

 });
```

is a JWT (JSON Web Token) that can't be stored on the database because it contains invalid characters and is too long and, I suspect, not the token I am looking for for sending notifications. Is there another way I should be finding the device token?

Answer (score 0):

For cordova, get plugin this way:

```
 window.FirebasePlugin.onTokenRefresh(function(token) {

        console.log(token);


    }, function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

So from the plugin and not from the currentUser or user instance.